# socket c# --> Python telegram bot

Tags: python, c#, sockets

I am writing a project whose essence is to output data from a c# python console application to a telegram bot. I decided to do this via sockets, but came to a dead end when an error occurred: "OSError: [WinError 10048] Usually only one use of the socket address is allowed (protocol/network address/port)"
please help with solving this problem

here is my code:

```
stop_output = False

@router.callback_query(lambda c: c.data == "start_button")
async def start_bots(call: CallbackQuery):
    global stop_output
    stop_output = False
    await call.answer()
    
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.bind(("localhost", 5000))
    server_socket.listen(1)

    while not stop_output:
        time.sleep(1)
        client_socket, address = server_socket.accept()

        data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")

        print(data)

        client_socket.close()
```

```
using (TcpClient clients = new TcpClient("localhost", 5000))
{
    using (NetworkStream stream = clients.GetStream())
    {
        string message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ArbitragVnytribirgevoi);
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: A TCP connection has three parameter 1) Source IP 2) Destination IP 3) Port number.  You can only have one connection where all three parameters are the same.  Error indicates you already have a connection with the same parameters.  From cmd.exe type following to see existing connections  >Netstat -A

Comment: I changed the port to 80, but the error did not disappear. The error occurs when the second user tries to get data from c#

Comment: HTTP uses TCP as the transport layer.  If you are using HTTP over TCP your data has to include  a valid HTTP message.  You are writing client code and sending to a HTTP server.  The message the TCP client is sending has to be HTTP.  Look at para : HTTP/1.1 example of request / response transaction at following : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP

Answer (score 0):

Socket 5000 is already used by `Windows UPnP`. Choose a socket that is not listed here.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers